# Flash Button Linking and Toggle

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Clicking one of 3 buttons shows price output in total.text
each button shows a different price.

code currently used for each button:

```
1    btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myButtonClick);
2    
3    function myButtonClick(ev:MouseEvent):void
4    {
5    var a:Number = Number(99) * Number(1.2);
6    total.text = String(a);
7    }
8
9   btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myButtonClick);
10   
11    function myButtonClick(ev:MouseEvent):void
12    {
13    var b:Number = Number(99) * Number(1.4);
14    total.text = String(b);
15    }
16
17  btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myButtonClick);
18   
19    function myButtonClick(ev:MouseEvent):void
20    {
21    var c:Number = Number(99) * Number(1.6);
22    total.text = String(c);
23    }
24
```

it works fine, but i really want to Add the value of button 2 and/or 3 if toggled to the value of button 1 and display it in total.text

eventually, i am trying to get choice of 5 buttons to toggle 1 of. that toggle will set the initial Number(99) value with something..99 or what not. and then if i toggle 1 button in a second set of 5 buttons, it will set value in the second Number(1.2).  and from there. the two toggled btn2 and btn3 would multiply total number in total.text.

i see where i can make a whole bunch of buttons with values calculated. but im sure there is a cleaner way to do that.
i am a total novice in flash and just kinda looking for a direction here. it would be awesome.

**Edit:**  Did a little research. hope I'm heading in right direction

ok, added variable number like

```
var modifier1:Number = 99;
var modifier2:Number = 1.2;
```

then called on those from the function like

```
var a:Number = Number(modifier1) * Number(modifier2);
```

now researching on how to make the modifier1 actually link up to toggle state of a button and assign it a value like 99 for toggled and 1 for not.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating a small class for all your buttons, it shall contain its **value**. You also need an object that will contain a list of these buttons, let's call it **Application**. When user clicks on Button1, it will set a field inside Application indicating the toggle - product of all values or just the button that was pressed. This then sets the actual text to whatever was passed *(I've called it valueText)*.

http://puu.sh/d1hP7/e25228352b.png

Here's some quick code, I haven't tested if it actually works, but It should be pretty easy to follow:

```
class Button {

    private var app:Application;
    public var value:Number;

    public function Button(app:Application, value:Number) {
        this.app = app;
        this.value = value;
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);
    }
    private function mouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
        app.displayText(value);
    }
}

class Application {

    private var buttonList:Vector.<Button> = new Vector.<Button>();
    public var isToggleOn:Boolean = false;

    public function Application() {
        buttonList.push(new Button(this, 0.98));
        buttonList.push(new Button(this, 0.75));
        buttonList.push(new Button(this, 0.88));
    }

    public function getProduct():Number {
        var sum:Number = 0;
        for(var button:Button in buttonList) {
            sum += button.value;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public function displayText(value:Number):void {
        valueText.text = isToggleOn ? getProduct() : value;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. ill take a look at it and see what I can break now :)

Comment: initially it does not like the Boolean isToggleOn = false; gives a syntax error. but ill google some stuff. as I said, im a novice :) I do like the flow chart, I can see what you saying there for sure. makes sense.

Comment: Ah that's right, I've been doing too much C++ lately. The syntax in AS3 will make it `var isToggleOn:Boolean = false;`